# Storing images and text locally from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, local

I am in need of learning to pull down images and text from a mysql database and storing them locally on the machine. The project I'm working on is to account for spotty internet connections, so what is supposed to happen is that the user will connect to the database once initially, and it should pull down all of the information they will need for their session and have it stored locally. Then if their internet goes out it will not matter because the information will have been stored locally. The issue is I have no idea where to start with this. I've looked into localStorage in HTML5/Javascript, but storing images looks over complicated with that method. It also doesn't have easy way of connecting to a database to download the info. It looks as if the easiest way to do this would be in php. I have found very little information on how to do so from hours of Google searching, and that is why I'm coming to you. Any information will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Cookies, lots and lots of cookies.

Comment: There has to be a better method than just plainly cookies...

Comment: Yes, stop being lazy and learn localstorage as you might need it in the future anyway. Also you clearly haven't looked into it, because it's easy to store images in localstorage. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_store_images_using_localstorage57?lang=en